# Почему не работает focus-visible?

Tags: html, css, html5, веб-программирование, frontend

Есть код.

```css
.link:focus {
  outline: 10px solid black;
}

.link:focus-visible {
  outline: 4px dashed darkorange;
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#">Ссылка</a>
```

Если я верно понял работу псевдокласса `focus-visible`, то он должен применить стили, прописанные внутри его тела, если посредством той же клавиши `tab` я переключусь на нужный элемент. Почему это не работает? Проверял в разных браузерах, в том числе, и в Мозиле.

Comment: вот тут в конце таблица совместимости - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible, и например про chrome - From version 67: this feature is behind the #enable-experimental-web-platform-features preference (needs to be set to enabled). To change preferences in Chrome, visit chrome://flags

Answer (score 0):

```css
css .link:focus {
  outline: 10px solid black;
}

.link:focu,
.link:visited {
  outline: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#">Ссылка</a>
```